# how to change the css of the parent div in javascript not jquery

Tags: javascript

I want to change the CSS of a parent div if I click the child of its parent div, not, for example if I click href tag. I want to change the CSS of its class="changed_area".

How can I do this?

```js
var up_btn = document.getElementsByClassName('up_btn');
var up_btn_length = up_btn.length;
var changed_area = document.getElementsByClassName('changed_area');
var changed_area_length = changed_area.length;

for (var i = 0; i < up_btn_length; i++) {
  up_btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    //alert('welcome');

    for (var i = 0; i < changed_area_length; i++) {

      if (changed_area[i].style.top == '-100%') {
        changed_area[i].style.top = '0%';
      } 
      else {
        changed_area[i].style.top = '-100%';
      }

    }

  });
}
```

```html
<?php foreach($questions As $question): ?>

  <div class="changed_area" style="width: 100px;">
    <div class="inside_ajax_part1">
      <div id="inside_left">
        <img src="<?php echo $Filter_customer->image; ?>" />
      </div>
      <div id="inside_right">
        <a class="up_btn" href="#">Up</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside_ajax_part2">
      <p>mohammed</p>
    </div>
  </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: what about https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp ?

Comment: I think you mean "ancestor" instead of "parent" and "descendant" instead of "child". Correct me if I'm wrong. See: [Ancestor, Descendant, Sibling, Parent, Child – Explained](https://sebastian.expert/ancestor-descendant-sibling-parent-child-explained/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

EDIT : better way to do this

```
 for (var i = 0; i < up_btn_length; i++) {
    up_btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var changed_area = up_btn[i].parentElement;
        if ( changed_area.classList.contains('changed_area') ) {
            changed_area.classList.remove('changed_area')
        }
        else {
            changed_area.classList.add('changed_area')
        }
        if(changed_area.style.top == '-100%') {
            changed_area.style.top = '0%';
        }
        else {
            changed_area.style.top = '-100%';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Also, if you want to be sure that the correct div will be selected, you can use the property 'parentElement' of 'up_btn[i]' (because currently if you don't have the same number of div and buttons, you will get an error). for exemple if you put another button without parentDiv, the 'changed_area[i]' will be undefined. I have edited my post with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just add event listener on parent and use `currentTarget`

```
const parent = document.getElementsByClassName('changed_area');// select parent
for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
  parent[i].addEventListener('click', (ev) => ev.currentTarget.className = 'clicked');
}
```

[Here is fiddle for it](https://jsfiddle.net/zpyxcvt8/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code affects all of your divs with class "changed_area", That I don't think it is what you intend.

To access a parent element with javascript you can use `parentElement`. To get the parent of parent of parent.... that meets some condition (like having a class) you can do this:

```
function Get_changed_area(targetElement){
    var parent = targetElement.parentElement;
    if(parent.hasClass('changed_area'))
        return parent;
    else Get_changed_area(parent)  //repeat the function for parent
}
for (var i = 0; i < up_btn_length; i++) {
   up_btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
   changed_area = Get_changed_area(up_btn[i]);
   if (changed_area.style.top == '-100%') {
    changed_area.style.top = '0%';
   } 
   else {
    changed_area.style.top = '-100%';
   }
  }
 }
```